# Aggregate specific field in java

Tags: hashmap

I have the below input data, what I want is to aggregate the duration field (field3) once field1 and field2 is repeated,

I tried the hashmap, but in my case there is 2 keys, and one value !

Input file:

```
date   Company Duration
20161014    IBM 234
20161014    IBM 132
20161014    DELL    223
20161014    DELL    23
20161014    DELL    12
20161015    IBM 122
20161015    IBM 654
20161015    IBM 347
20161015    IBM 997
20161015    DELL    666
```

Needed output:

```
Date   Company Total duration
20161014    IBM 366
20161015    IBM 2120
20161014    DELL    258
20161015    DELL    666
```

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupingBy with a stream :

```
 items.stream().collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getDate, mapping(Item::getCompany, toSet())), Collectors.summingInt(Item::getTotalDuration)));
```

Comment: Thanks @Isukthar, can you share an example, date field is just String,